# Limit results in Handlebars #each without using extra helpers

Tags: javascript, css, loops, handlebars.js, zendesk

So, I know I would be able to solve this issue IF I were able to implement extra handlebars helpers, but that is not an option.

We are using a third-party back end system for our Help Desk [ZenDesk], which uses handlebars as its general markup for dynamic content. I have a section on the home page of our Help Center website that I want to list the first 5-6 FAQ articles, and then a SEE MORE link underneath for the user to see the rest of the articles in that particular section.

Out of the box, they allow us to use the IF and IS conditional, but no comparative aside from TRUE or FALSE, no greater than, no less than, no greater or equal than, etc. I wrote up a simple helper that would allow for this, but no matter where I put it in the templates available to us, it would always generate an error that the function was not valid.

After discussing this with this application's support team, I was informed that NO CUSTOM HELPERS ARE ALLOWED TO BE USED. I have to rely SOLELY on HTML, CSS and JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY to find the solution.

So.... Does anybody know of a possible solution of how I can cap off a handlebars #each loop at 5 iterations by using CSS or JAVASCRIPT?

**UPDATE: 09/05/2018:**

Here's the #each loop I am using for the section "Frequently Asked Questions"

```
<h2>Frequently Asked Questions</h2>
  <section class="section faq-base">
    <section class="categories">

      <ul class="">
        {{#each categories}}
          {{#if ../has_multiple_categories}}
            <li class="">
              <a href='{{url}}' class="">
                <h4 class="blocks-item-title">{{name}}</h4>
              </a>
            </li>
          {{else}}
            {{#each sections}}
                    {{#is id //ID FOR FREQUENTLY ASKED QUESTIONS SECTION}}
                <div class="accordion homeFAQ" id="homeFAQ">
                  {{#each articles}}
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="heading{{@index}}">
                      <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse{{@index}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse{{@index}}">
                          {{title}}
                        </button>
                      </h5>
                    </div>

                    <div id="collapse{{@index}}" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading{{@index}}" data-parent="#homeFAQ">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        {{body}}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  {{/each}}
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                      <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <a href="{{url}}" class="btn btn-link collapsed">...SEE MORE</a>
                      </h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                    {{/is}}

            {{/each}}
          {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    </section>
  </section>
```

As you can see from the above code, I am inserting the FAQ into a Bootstrap Accordion, and at the end is the `...SEE MORE` button

Comment: Please share sample of current home page code?

Comment: Edited the Original Issue

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a `display:none` to the articles by default, then use JS to count the number of articles on the page, based on the class (or something) of the articles on the page, and then use JS again to remove the `display:none` from the first 5-6 articles?  May not be the most elegant approach but should be one way to accomplish what you are looking for.